# Given a GUID representing a user in Active Directory, how would I use this to determine the distinguished name?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Given a GUID representing a user in Active Directory, how would I use this to determine the user's "distinguished name" using C#?

The GUID is retrieved earlier in our application using directoryEntry.Guid;
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.guid.aspx)

Comment: By GUID to you mean SID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)? I'm aware there are Guid's floating around in places, but SIDs are often mistaken for them =)

Comment: The GUID as specified by the DirectoryEntry.Guid property
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.guid.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've made it clear a GUID is what you're searching on, try this:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public static class DomainHelpers
{    
    public string GetDistinguishedName(string domain, string guid)
    {
        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain); 
        var userPrincipal  = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Guid, guid);

        return userPrincipal.DistinguishedName;
    }
}
```

I've used this with `IdentityType.Name` so can't be sure it'll work for `IdentityType.Guid`, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the distinguishedName from the DirectoryEntry directly:

```
public string GetDN(DirectoryEntry de)  
{  
    return de.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();  
}
```

If you still need to [bind via GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) you can do that as well:

```
public string GetDNviaGUID(Guid queryGuid)  
{  
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<GUID=" + queryGuid + ">");  
    return de.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
}
```

The following properties and methods don't work when you bind via GUID or SID: ADsPath, Name, Parent, GetObject, Create, Delete, CopyHere, MoveHere.

You can get around this by retrieving the object via GUID, getting its distinguished name, and then binding using the DN.

Answer (score -2):

You do not. The GUID is not a conversion to start with, it is totally random unique.

Basically, you have to have your SID, then CALL into active diretory and get the User object that has the same sid, then read out the distinguished name from that. Note that this is not a CONVERSION, o that is why the answer is no.

if a conversion back would be possible, the SID would be useless for conversion purposes, as I could always generate a SID from your distinguished name, which is - within the domain - public.